# Constraints are not honoring size classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, autolayout, constraints

I'm trying to convert iPhone and iPad storyboards into single one that is aware of Size Classes. For this I need to be able to change one particular image width between iPhone and iPad and also to enable/disable one constraint on the iPad.

Here is screenshot from my image width constraint:
[image]

As I understand it should use 230 when run on iPhones and 400 otherwise, correct?

Here is screenshot from the constraint I need to disable when not on iPad:

[image]

For some reason when running this on iPhone 5/6/6+ simulator I'm getting `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.` warning:

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f99f17704e0 H:[UIImageView:0x7f99f1770370(400)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f99f17718d0 UIView:0x7f99f1771710.width == IATextFieldEx:0x7f99f1768be0.width + 160>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f99f1773210 UIImageView:0x7f99f1770370.width == IATextFieldEx:0x7f99f17639e0.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f99f17734e0 H:[UIView:0x7f99f1771710]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f99f1771620 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f99f1773580 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7f99f1771710]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f99f1771620 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f99f1492ce0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x7f99f1771620(320)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f99f1732250 IATextFieldEx:0x7f99f1768be0.width == IATextFieldEx:0x7f99f17639e0.width>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f99f17718d0 UIView:0x7f99f1771710.width == IATextFieldEx:0x7f99f1768be0.width + 160>
```

Am I missing something obvious? Why is Xcode still using w:Any h:Any constraints when run on iPhone?

Comment: My limited experience with size constraints so far is that if they're not [X] installed, they won't apply. Odd that your first screenshot doesn't even show an install option for the size class?

Comment: @remus: the first one shows "installed" as default. so it should be enabled apply always, no?

Comment: That's the global constraint / default, not the size class one. The size class constraints always appear with an X beside them. And if you click the +, it'll let you add more size classes.

Comment: But the global should apply if size class one is not specified. Correct?

Comment: Yeah, it should, and that's why I'm a little confused why the "Installed" box doesn't show up in that screenshot.

Comment: What do you mean? It says [X] Installed there...

Comment: That's the global constraint not the class size constraint. Try deleting the class size constraint and creating it again?

Answer (score 0):

Can't easily put this in a comment, so it's here in an answer. It should show up with the size class installed like this. If it's not, something has gone wrong - try recreating the constraint?

[image]

Comment: This configuration should be equal to the default one which I posted on the first screenshot. Am I correct? I mean, behavior should be identical.